# Тонкости работы css.content

Tags: css, content

Задача: размещаю легенду в виде пар "термин":"значение". На форме это выглядит так:

```
<table class="legend-table">
<tr><td>Destination</td><td>адрес подсети или хоста назначения</td></tr>
<tr><td>Gateway</td><td>адрес шлюза, через который данный маршрут доступен</td></tr>
...
</table>
```

Далее, хочу сделать так, чтобы перед каждой расшифровкой значения шло тире - `– | &ndash; | &#8211;`. Чтобы вставить просто минус, использую стиль:

```
table.legend-table tr td:last-child:before {
    content: " - "
}
```

Но хочется, чтобы это было именно тире. Я сделал промежуточный вариант, вставив символ тире в код, благо исходник в UTF-8 и проблемы нет:

```
table.legend-table tr td:last-child:before {
    content: " – "
}
```

Но мне хотелось знать, есть ли нормальный вариант вставить HTML-код перед элементом посредством CSS (то есть `&#8211;` или `&ndash;`)

В идеале было бы найти способ вообще вставки чего угодно перед элементом, например иконки или глифа, или еще чего средствами CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В свойство `content` символы юникода могут записываться в 16-битной форме без префикса `U+` с экранированием обратным слешем `\` . Напрмер, среднее тире `&#8211;` имеет код `U+2013` . Полный список символов и их кодов можно найти на https://unicode-table.com/ru/

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
}
li:before{
  content:'\2013';
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>asdas</li>
  <li>asdas</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Отлично, в моем случае получается `content: '\00A0\2013\00A0';`. А как вставлять HTML? Я попробовал составить тег `<i>` из Unicode, экранируя каждый, но он вставился как символ, без парсинга в виде HTML. Такая возможность в принципе есть, не в курсе? Как это сделать JS я знаю )

Comment: Через `content` вставить html-код нельзя.